A question to the proof of Lemma 9 in "Multiple solutions for the Brezis-Nirenberg problem"
I'm currently puzzled by the final portion of the proof for Lemma 9 in the paper "Multiple solutions for the Brezis-Nirenberg problem"(DOI:10.57262/ade/1355867873). In particular, I'm unsure about the conclusion reached in the provided image. 
From the author's notation, the set $\mathcal{U}(\delta)$ is defined as follows:

where $M$ is a $N+1$-dimensional manifold which consists precisely of the positive
solutions to Yamabe equation in $\mathbb{R}^N$.
In my understanding, the Krasnoselski genus of $\mathcal{U}(\delta)$ is no less than $N+1$. It seems that I may have missed some key points, or there could be some typos here.
